# Binding a control within a control

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a page which is databound to an object like so `this.DataContext = anObject;`, the properties of that object binds perfectly.

But now I have a control within that.

```
<Control2></Control2>
```

And in the constructor for that control I set `this.DataContext = anotherObject;`

The problem I seem to be having when I do this is that this Control2 seems to be double bound when I do `{Binding aProperty}` it complains about it not being in `anotherObject` and when I bind `{Binding anotherProperty}` it'll complain about it not having it in `anObject`

Any ideas.

Comment: This question is not so clear. So you have anObject as the DataContext of a Control. Then you want to set anObject.SomeProperty as the DataContext of a nested control (Control2)?

Comment: when I put `{Binding aProperty}` that's in the xaml to display in a TextBlock. the data context is set in code.

Comment: please post the xaml structure and the object's structure and tell what you want

Comment: This question lacks clarity, short example Xaml and C# code required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the data context is being set by the page after you've set it in the constructor. Thus you're getting two different binding sources reported at different times.

Try listening to the DataContextChanged event in your control.

Comment: sorry i'm developing for WP7 it's not available.

Comment: Unlike WPF, Silverlight controls don't have a DataContextChanged event.  You can add something similar, using an approach such as http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38559/Silverlight-DataContext-Changed-Event, but it's not something you get 'out of the box'.